# exec() not working when trying to execute PHP script

Tags: php, permissions, terminal, exec, shell-exec

I am have a PHP script called process_item.php that can be run from terminal. I want to create a web script that can run the same file using `exec()`. My web script(process_item_online.php) looks like below:

```
ini_set("display_errors",true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$item = $_GET['item'];
echo "Received request for item $item<br>";
$cmd = "/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/process_item.php $item";
exec($cmd);
echo "Processed using command - $cmd";
```

The script `process_item.php` has 777 permissions. When I run the above script in browser, I get both these lines printed correctly:

```
Received request for item 10023444AJK
Executed command - /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/process_item.php 10023444AJK
```

However nothing else happens. As in, the database is not updated, the logs are not written etc. I do not get any error on the browser either. I am sure this is a permission issue since it works fine from the terminal. Can anyone give me any pointers on how I can make this work from the browser?

Comment: Do you have `safe_mode` enabled?

Comment: @AbraCadaver - I do not see such an option in phpinfo()...where can I check it?

Comment: Please change the exec to `exec($cmd, $output, $return_var)` and provide the output of `var_dump($output, $return_var);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver - I did ini_get and safe_mode is disabled

Comment: I believe that executables should hold 755 instead of 777.

Comment: @DerVO - result is `array(0) { } int(255)` and the two echo statements I have previously

Comment: *"As in, the database is not updated..."* - The problem may lie in the SQL and not the `exec()` - if the `exec()` runs, then it's most likely elsewhere.

Comment: as it returns status code 255 there is an error in your process_item.php  , can you turn error reporting in that file and see again what it will output

Comment: @Fred-ii- that is only for safety concerns right? 777 means even more free permission, I think. I agree that I should put it at 755 later, right now I just desperately want to get this running :( Need to give this URL to someone else..

Comment: Ok. Yeah, 755 is safer yet like I said, the problem may lie in the SQL. Does running `process_item.php` on its own work ok?

Comment: I also suspect that running from a browser you may need to CD to that directory first

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, it works fine. I have already mentioned in the question.. " I am sure this is a permission issue since it works fine from the terminal." Not sure what is messing up here...

Comment: @BojanT - I am using full paths in the exec, no need to CD

Comment: Can you make another proccess_item2.php that echos something with same permissions and ownership as original file and see what will happen, also var_dump `var_dump($output, $return_var);`